# Simplicial space of a total space of a classifying bundle for $G$

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, simplicial-stuff, classifying-spaces

I am reading lecture notes on topology and the total space $E(U(N))$ is given as a geometric realization of a simplicial space $$E(U(N))=|[n]\rightarrow U(N)^{n+1}|$$ Here I am confused because

1) the details about face and degeneracy maps are missing. What are they exactly?

2) I am confused that left handside depends on $n$  and right handside does not. Is it correct that I should have written $$E(U(N))=|[n]\rightarrow U(N)^{n+1}|$$
 whatever that means. 
 Probably, I wasn't careful to take the notes in the class. Wikipedia and ncatlab provide the simplicial space for the  $BG$ and they give the special case for $EU$ geometrically without explaining the face/degeneracy maps.

Comment: which lecture notes are you referring to? can you give link?

Comment: The right hand side has incorrect indexing $U(n)$ should be $U(N)$. You should look up the Bar construction. This is an example of one, the face and degeneracy maps will be explained in any reference on that, but the idea is that we are doing the face maps through multiplication in $U(N)$ and the degeneracy maps through inserting the identity.

Comment: @ConnorMalin thanks, could you advise any reference?

Comment: @ConnorMalin that more or less solves my problem, because I couldn't get $n-1$ by $n-1$ unitary matrix from $n$ by $n$ unitary matrix. Deleting row and column didn't help but now I don't need it.

Comment: https://people.math.binghamton.edu/malkiewich/bar.pdf